# Overriding a library's reference to "R.style.someTheme"

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-styles

I'm using a library that has it's own style defined for a dialog.

It calls the style like this:

```
dlg.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, darkTheme ? 
R.style.customDlgDarkTheme : R.style.customDlgLightTheme);
```

where `R.style.*` are defined in its own `styles.xml`

How would I override this in to apply my own font/styling to it, in my `styles.xml` or elsewhere?

So far, I've tried this but it has no effect:

```
    <style name="ChangelogDialogLightTheme">
        <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/AppTheme</item>
        <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/Alert.Button.Positive</item>
        <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/Alert.Button.Negative</item>
        <item name="buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle">@style/Alert.Button.Neutral</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: how about editting the library sources?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Imported modules are read-only, and I would prefer not to import the entire source or override the class into my app to just change button styles. I was told that this can be achieved in styles.xml, but can't find a suitable example anywhere.

Comment: Add parent theme (whatever theme library is using) to your `ChangelogDialogLightTheme`

Answer (score 1):

Change your custom style name from **ChangelogDialogLightTheme** to either **customDlgDarkTheme** or **customDlgLightTheme** whichever one you want to override.

Comment: My mistake, I changed the example in the question to make it more general - thanks for the answer, but they're the same in my app